# Save UDP packets from x amount of seconds in a pcap file

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, scapy

I am trying to save UDP data packets which I receive from a sensor to my PC through ethernet connection. I want to save the UDP data in the form of a pcap file.

So far I have written the following code to save 1 packet of data. I ran my code then opened up the saved pcap file using wireshark and compared it to the output from the raw wireshark data. Lines 0000 - 0010 from packet 1 are the same but line 0020 is different. test.pcap only has 42 bytes captured whereas from wireshark packet 1 has 1236 bytes captured.

Correct me if I am wrong but I think this is due to my code not giving enough time to collect all the data from the packet. **I was hoping to get help in modifying my code below so that it saves the pcap file in time intervals. For example a pcap file will be saved every 5 seconds.**

```
from scapy.all import wrpcap, Ether, IP, UDP

pkts = [Ether(src=" ", dst=" ") / IP(src=" ", dst=" ") / UDP(src=" ", dst=" ")]

wrpcap('test.pcap', [pkts])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, let me know if you are still getting less packets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import struct
import os
import argparse

from scapy.all import sniff, sendp, hexdump, linehexdump, get_if_list, get_if_hwaddr
from scapy.all import Packet, IPOption
from scapy.all import ShortField, IntField, LongField, BitField, FieldListField, FieldLenField
from scapy.all import IP, TCP, UDP, Raw
from scapy.layers.inet import _IPOption_HDR
from scapy.all import raw
from scapy.all import bytes_hex
import hashlib
import pcapng.blocks as blocks
from pcapng import FileWriter


counter = 1

def get_if():
    ifs=get_if_list()
    iface=None
    for i in get_if_list():
        if "enp1s0f1" in i:
            iface=i
            break;
    if not iface:
        print("Cannot find eth0 interface")
        exit(1)
    return iface


def main():
    global counter
    ifaces = [i for i in os.listdir('/sys/class/net/') ]
    iface = get_if()
    print(("sniffing on %s" % iface))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    writer = FileWriter(args.outfile, shb)

    orig_packets = sniff(filter='tcp and port 5201',iface = iface)
    for packet in orig_packets:
        spb = shb.new_member(blocks.SimplePacket)
        spb.packet_data = bytes(packet)
        writer.write_block(spb)
        print("C=",counter)
        counter=counter+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("outfile", type=argparse.FileType("wb"))
    args = parser.parse_args()

    shb = blocks.SectionHeader(
    options={
        "shb_hardware": "artificial",
        "shb_os": "python",
        "shb_userappl": "python-pcapng",
    })
    idb = shb.new_member(
    blocks.InterfaceDescription,
    link_type=1,
    options={
        "if_description": "Hand-rolled",
        "if_os": "Python",
        "if_filter": [(0, b"tcp port 5201 and host 192.168.1.3")],
    },)

    main()
```